# Как данные JSON сделать рекурсией?

Tags: javascript, json, рекурсия

Есть данные в формате json

```
{
  "root": {
    "design": {
      "options": [{"val": 1}, {"val": 2}, {"val": 3}]
    },
    "comments": [0, 1, 2],
    "data": {
      "inner": [{"array": [{"x": 35}]}, {"array": [{"y": 15}]}]
    }
  }
}
```

** Как сделать в таком формате ?**

```
{
  "root.design.options.0.val": 1,
  "root.design.options.1.val": 2,
  "root.design.options.2.val": 3,

  "root.comments.0": 0,
  "root.comments.1": 1,
  "root.comments.2": 2,
  "root.data.inner.0.array.0.x": 35,
  "root.data.inner.1.array.y": 15
}
```

Comment: прочитайте ваш json в массив. далее в цикле перебирайте значения и и ключи и делайте такую строку которая вам нужна. это касается php, за другие не скажу

Answer (score 0):

1) Переводишь json в объект js
2) Создаешь функцию для прохода циклом объекта, которая вызовет сама себя, если там будет объект

```
function fun (obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
  switch (typeof(obj[key])) {
    case 'object':
       fun (obj[key]); // углубляешься по объекту
       break;
    default:
       // здесь записываешь конечное значение,
  }
}
```

Примерно так